# Play Store not showing the new version deployed at the first time

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking

In my Android application, I have a function that forces users to update the application. I have an API that returns the latest VERSION CODE deployed in the play store and based on this VERSION CODE, I display a dialog to the user with a button to go to the play store page of my application. The problem is that the FIRST time the user is redirected to the play store, the usual page of the application is displayed (the one with the "open" button instead of the "update" button). But on the second redirection, the play store page displays the "update" button.

this is the code that i'm using to redirect users to the play store.

```
final String appPackageName = mContext.getPackageName(); // package name of the app
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                              intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                              intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                              intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                              intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
             intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));

                        try {
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);

                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

                       
             intent.setData(Uri.parse(""https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + 
             appPackageName));

               mContext.startActivity(intent);

                        }
```

**I would like the play store detect the new version of the app on the first redirect.**
Is this a google play store bug? or did I miss something? I really need your help! Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is a play store bug